# В параметры метода приходят неправильные данные

Tags: java

У меня есть метод tryToReproduce() который вызывает у каждого домена на игровом поле переопределенный метод reproduce() из суперкласса Animal . Метод reproduce() должен устанавливать на рандомную клетку нового животного этого же вида .

Теперь суть проблемы :
Я вызываю из метода tryToReproduce()

`private void tryToReproduce() {

```
    for (int i = 0; i < areaData.getArea().length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < areaData.getArea()[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < areaData.getArea()[i][j].getAnimals_in_cell().size(); k++) {
                if (!areaData.getArea()[i][j].getAnimals_in_cell().isEmpty()) {
                    areaData.getArea()[i][j].getAnimals_in_cell().get(k).reproduce(areaData.getArea()[i][j].getAnimals_in_cell().get(k), i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

метод reproduce() одного из доменных классов. Далее, в методе reproduce()

```
public void reproduce(Animal animal, int width, int length) {
    int randomWidth = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, areaData.getArea().length);
    int randomLength = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, areaData.getArea()[0].length);
    areaData.getArea()[randomWidth][randomLength].setAnimals_in_cell(new AnimalFactory().create(AnimalType.DUCK));
}
```

я вызываю setter рандомной клетки на поле и передаю ей нового животного которого я создаю в фабрике

```
 public Animal create(AnimalType type) {

    switch (type) {
        case BEAR:
            animalType = new Bear();
        case BOAR:
            animalType = new Boar();
        case BUFFALO:
            animalType = new Buffalo();
        case CATERPILLAR:
            animalType = new Caterpillar();
        case DEER:
            animalType = new Deer();
        case DUCK:
            animalType = new Duck();
```

. И тут случилось то , чего я не ожидал ) Допустим в setter клетки я передаю new Duck() . Когда я перехожу в метод setter - у меня во входных данных приходит другой доменный класс (new Wolf())
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] . Как это происходит  - я совершенно не пойму .
Как мне добиться того , чтобы в сеттер приходил корректный класс (тот, который я передал) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В switch/case нужно не забывать делать явный `break`:

```
switch (type) {
    case BEAR:
        animalType = new Bear();
        break;
    case BOAR:
        animalType = new Boar();
        break;
    case BUFFALO:
        animalType = new Buffalo();
        break;
    case CATERPILLAR:
        animalType = new Caterpillar();
        break;
    case DEER:
        animalType = new Deer();
        break; 
    case DUCK:
        animalType = new Duck();
        break;
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное !Теперь все работает как нужно) Как же этот break бесит в свичах ...